# How to get the number of objects at a pixel position?

Tags: openlayers-2

Is it possible to get the total number of objects (Lines,Points) at a given pixel position in the map?

Answer (score 2):

You can create Point geometry from given pixel position and calculate number of other geometries of layer's features which intersects this one. See [OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.intersects](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.intersects) method.

Comment: But I think this function only determines if the two geometries intersects..I would like to get all the overlapped features at pixel position because SelectFeature only gets the topmost object..There is a function getObjectsAt(x, y) in nokia maps api which returns an array with all the overlapped objects at that pixel position. Do we have something similar in openlayers?